# Finding least common multiples by prime factorization is not always correct?

Tags: least-common-multiple

I found out that the algorithm for finding LCM of N given numbers by prime factiorization (as on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Finding_least_common_multiples_by_prime_factorization/)) is not always correct. For example:
$$
LCM(8, 21) = 2^3*7^1 = 8*7=56
$$
Which is obviously not true.
Is there a rule saying that for some numbers this algorithm won't give correct answer? Or something else I'm not aware of?

*I'm sorry for my poor english :(*

Comment: You forgot that $21 = 3\cdot 7$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: LCM is not $2^3\times 7$ but it is $2^3\times 3\times 7$.

You can also use the well known fact that LCM*HCF = Product of numbers. HCF of $8, 21$ is $1$. So, $LCM=8*21$

Comment: Sarcasm huh...  Pleasure @Rohan, you know... Things go worse sometimes

Comment: Why what happened?? I am not sarcastic.

Comment: wait @Rohan, there are more than one things to say, so I m gonna invite you to a chatroom